# Reassembly lube very thick in cold weather

Tags: lubrication

Last night it was around 40 F and the reassembly lube (Permatex) I was using to butter the cylinder head parts was VERY thick and difficult to smear, even with a small paint brush. Should I put it in warm water to improve the viscosity?

Comment: No expert on this, but to me I would want to know if it is just cold or if it's bad. I would store it room temp and if it is still hard, use something else.

Comment: How does assembly lube go bad @Chris? I'm not challenging you, I've just not heard of it happening.

Comment: Yes defn not an expert, but the web lists various ways lube grease gas bad inc age separation, and contamination. If you have a tub of lube 10 years old that's been used, gone through temp cycles and possibly stored dodgy, the web seems to say it could happen.

Comment: @Chris - The internet is NEVER wrong, dontchano? And I'm a French Supermodel. :o)

Comment: Lol strut that thing on the catwalk dude

Answer (score 1):

If it helps get the goo spread, you're not going to hurt it by heating it up. It's not going to hurt your assembly or the lube itself.